# Server can not decrypt messages sent by Android 4.2

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

After looking through MANY questions and answers here around cryptographic issues in Android 4.2 and above (specifically, things encrypted prior to 4.2 can no longer be decrypted in 4.2) but none of the answers seem to work for my case.

We have a server side system that accepts AES encrypted payloads from our various device clients (be they Javascript, iOS, Android, or Windows), decrypts the data and then.. does whatever it needs to.  This has been working fine until we recently upgraded our Android client to API Level 19.  Now the server (which is written in C# and uses the standard .NET  cryptographic libraries) can no longer decrypt the messages as the PKCS5Padding is corrupted.  All the other clients continue to work with the server just fine.

Here is our encrypt method:

```
private static String encryptString(String plainText, byte[] key, byte[] salt, byte[] iv) {
    try{
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        KeySpec keyspec = new PBEKeySpec(keyToCharArray(key), salt,
                getEncryptionKeyIterations(), 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keyspec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES")
                , new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to encrypt message", ex);
        throw new InvalidDataException("Unable to encrypt message");
    }
}
```

The IV is generated using the following method:

```
public static byte[] getRandomIv() throws InvalidDataException {
    try {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        kgen.init(128, sr);
        return kgen.generateKey().getEncoded();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create random IV", ex);
        throw new InvalidDataException("Unable to create random IV");
    }
}
```

Some of the threads I have seen on here say to replace SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG") with SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto") to use Java Crypto rather than OpenSSL.  For us this makes NO difference to the decrypting at the other end.

I also tried switching to SpongyCastle, but this did not fix the issue.

The key we supply is the user password, salted with a known salt, and then SHA256 hashed.  This is a known quantity on the server as well, where the key is strengthened using the same algorithm prior to decryption.

**EDIT**

It appears it may have indeed been the IV generation. Strange as it may sound, switching to a simpler IV generation just using SecureRandom seemed to "fix" the issue.

Comment: How do you communicate the IV with the server? Do you also get this issue for long ciphertexts?

Comment: The IV is pre-pended to the ciphertext as the first 24 (base64) characters of the message.  The server then extracts the IV from the message.  I have not noticed any issues with long ciphertexts at all.  All the clients work the same way (including the iOS client which is in Objective-C).

Comment: Using secret key as IV is overshooting, simple `SecureRandom` is enough. Also, the result of the `getRandomIv()` method as it is written now is definitely larger than required for AES/CBC IV.

Comment: If it were 4.4, I'd point to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40578  If you're hashing the input to PBKDF2 (not sure why you're doing that), you'd definitely run into this issue.

Comment: Write a simple test, that uses known plain text, key and IV and reuses as much of your current code as possible, and run it on emulator with different API versions. If it reproduces different results then you will have a minimal examples and a list of API versions where it differs.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin `getRandomIV()` seems to return 128 bit / 16 bytes, I'm agreeing that generating a key is overdoing it, but the method seems to work fine otherwise.

Comment: @kroot we are hashing the input because the server needs to decrypt it, and the pre-shared secret is the sha256 hash of the user's password.  This enables us to log a user in without sending the user's password down the wire.

Comment: @Oleg and owlstead Thanks for your comments regarding the over-engineering :)  I'll run some quick tests using a simplified version that just uses SecureRandom for the IV and see how that goes.

Comment: Also, regarding SecureRandom.  It may not have been as random as you may have thought on APIs 16 through 18. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was the IV generation.  Although the original code generates a 128bit key (AES with KeyGenerator outputs a 128bit key, as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html), it seems to no longer work properly.

Changing the code to:

```
public static byte[] getRandomIv() throws InvalidDataException {
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] output = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(output);
        return output;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create random IV", ex);
        throw new InvalidDataException("Unable to create random IV");
    }
}
```

lets the library decrypt messages from the server and successfully log in.  We tested this on a range of API levels back to API Level 10 and it works well.  Thanks for your help guys.